# Помогите с ::before

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как с помощью ::before сделать вот так чтобы текст вертикально был ровным по левой линии?[image]

У меня получается вот так: [image] А когда ставлю `float`, вторая строка текста уходит под квадратик. Нужно чтобы было как на первом изображении. 
На размер плюсов не обращайте внимания.

```css
.plus_item li:before {
 content: '+';
 color: #fff;
 background: #445161;
 margin-right: 8px;
 display: block;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Свой код приведите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приблизительно так

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.list__item {
  padding-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  list-style: none;
}

.list__item::before {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim cupiditate non velit quos obcaecati, perferendis. Voluptas adipisci fugiat, sed quam non modi harum praesentium, cupiditate culpa alias doloremque nobis officiis!</li>
  <li class="list__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi maxime, doloremque. A esse aspernatur odio tempore, asperiores, nemo iste saepe corporis ea voluptatibus doloribus molestiae officiis quas, illo dignissimos deserunt.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

есть миллион и один способ решения этой задачи, но первое, что пришло в голову

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.block__text {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.block__text::before {
  content: "+";
  color: #fff;
  background: #445161;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus minus laborum velit quae perspiciatis maxime aliquam cupiditate quo, itaque quia!</div>
</div>
```